# How to test using jasmine and easyXDM

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, easyxdm

I have an angular app running through an iframe and use easyXDM for a few tasks but mostly to resize the iframe window. I'm currently trying to write some tests with jasmine but am running into an issue where easyXDM throws an error because the provider doesn't communicate with the consumer because I'm not running tests through the parent website.

I'm trying to figure out if I can set a value in angular and overwrite it during tests so the socket for easyXDM doesn't get instantiated. I'm also open to other potential solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by adding a variable to ngConstants in Grunfile.js. My code then checks this variable and instantiates an easyXDM socket only when the variable is set to true. In the case when I'm testing, grunt test, I set it to false.